# Add a file to a specific folder with gradle build

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am currently working with a project (using gradle) that needs a properties file in the same package to the class that consumes it (I can't change this config). I have added the file in my package, but when I execute the gradle build command omits the file, and only adds the .class file. The app is deployed as a war file.

I have tried editing the war task, but I can't find the way to make the properties file to be added:

```
war {
        from('src/main/com/foo/bar') {
            include 'b.properties'
            into 'WEB-INF/classes/com/foo/bar'
        }
}
```

The war task does execute (I have added a prinln and it executes). Also, I have tried changing the paths, but no results. Also replacing from('path') to from (file('path')), but still doesn't seem to add the file anywhere.

How should I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything stopping you from following Gradle's convention for resources?
Eg put your property file at `src/main/resources/com/foo/bar/b.properties`

If you do this you won't need any task customisations

Comment: It's a dependency from an external library that I can't control. If I add the properties in the resources folder, the jar doesn't work, that's the reason I'm trying to put this file into a specific location.  All the other properties files are located inside resources folder.

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"? Perhaps this property file is inside one of your dependency jars and you are trying to override it by putting it in `WEB-INF/classes` which is "higher" in the classpath ordering?